# what to write in configuration for mail function in wamp server setup?

Tags: gmail, wamp, sendmail

I just installed wamp server. At the end of the installation, it is showing this window:

[image]

I am going to use gmail  for mail in my project. I don't know what to write in this window. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to enter **SMTP** mail server and email you want to use (If you have any else you can click next). if you don't have any SMTP server set uped. php **mail()** will not work on your local server (WAMP)

**SMTP server** like :-

```
mail.mysite.com
```

email :-

```
youremail@email.com
```

You can also change these settings from your **php.ini** anytime

```
SMTP = mail.mydomain.com
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost
```

Change these settings with your settings

Comment: so, what if I want to send mail using gmail's smtp server?

Comment: you need to enter mail server domain in that if it works